# I there a way to update the boot record of reused hard drive to find Windows partition without reformatting it?

Tags: multi-boot, grub, uefi

I assembled a new computer. Specifically I added 2 SSD (one for system and one for home).

I reused my old hard drive which has two partitions on it: One with Linux and one with Windows. It has a MBR. I don’t want to reformat the drive and lose the Windows partition. I want to use this hard drive for two things:

1. Be able to boot Windows (`os-prober` currently only finds the Linux partition).
2. Merge the Linux partitions (it is split up in `/`, `swap`, `/boot` and `/home`) to use the partition as storage (I guess I can simply the unwanted partitions and grow the `/home` partition?)

Is there a way to achieve this without reformatting the drive and losing my Windows partition?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid reformatting the hard disk drive? Do you actually have Windows already installed on the hard disk drive so you don’t want to start from scratch.

Comment: Yes, as I said I used this hard drive on my old system to boot, so there is a bootable linux and windows partition on it.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Since you used the old hard drive previously to boot, you may continue to do so in the new computer.

From there, you may clone partitions or whatever you would like to do to end up with things on your new SSDs.

To achieve your stated goal, you should not need to do  the thing you state in the question title.

Answer (score 0):

My problem seems not to be solvable, because according to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dual_boot_with_Windows#Bootloader_UEFI_vs_BIOS_limitations I cannot boot from UEFI mode to BIOS mode on another disk.

Comment: That doesn't make your problem unsolvable. UEFI is more modern but you can still [choose which mode to use](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/boot-to-uefi-mode-or-legacy-bios-mode).